# Does the product rule for derivatives always work?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra

In school, we learn the product rule for derivatives, $\frac{d}{dx}\left[fg \right] = \frac{df}{dx}g+f\frac{dg}{dx}$.  Later, we find  that this rule also works for matrices.  And later, I learned it works for [screws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory).  Everywhere I turn, the rule works.

Does this rule work for all algebras which admit multiplication and a derivative, based on the properties of those operations, or is there a particular subcategory of algebras for which it works (and I just happen to have been most interested in those nice well-behaved algebras so far!)?

Comment: Well, the question is what you mean by a "derivative".  The product rule (together with linearity) is often taken as the _definition_ of a "derivative" in a generalized setting (called a *derivation*).

Comment: Not necessarily.  Trivial counter example.  What is the derivative of the product $g(x)=f(x)\cdot 0$, using the product rule? Suppose by itself, $f(x)$ were not a differentiable function.  Youd be forced to evaluate $f'(x)$, but this is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say we have $4$ Banach spaces, $V,X,Y,Z$, a non-empty open set $A\subseteq V$ and we have the following maps:

- A differentiable map $f:A \to X$
- A differentible map $g:A \to Y$
- A bilinear continuous map $\omega:X \times Y \to Z$.

Then, we can consider the map $h:A \to Z$ defined as
\begin{align}
h(x) &= \omega(f(x), g(x))
\end{align}
Then, $h$ will also be differentiable and we have the following formula for the derivative: at any point $\alpha\in A$ and for all $\xi\in V$, we have
\begin{align}
Dh_{\alpha}[\xi] &= \omega(Df_{\alpha}[\xi], g(\alpha)) + \omega(f(\alpha), Dg_{\alpha}[\xi])
\end{align}
Here, the map $\omega$ is to be interpreted as a product between elements of $X$ and elements of $Y$, giving you an element in $Z$, and accordingly, we interpret $h$ as the product (with respect to $\omega$) of $f$ and $g$. Notice that if we suppress the use of $\omega$ from the notation and denote it as a usual $\cdot$ for multiplication, the result looks very familiar:
\begin{align}
D(f\cdot g)_{\alpha}[\xi] &= Df_{\alpha}[\xi] \cdot g(\alpha) + f(\alpha) \cdot Dg_{\alpha}[\xi]
\end{align}
It follows the usual rule of "differentiate the first keep the second plus keep the first differentiate the second" (being careful to evaluate things at the right place). I'm not sure if this is the most general setting (and I certainly wouldn't be surprised if it isn't), but it covers a lot of scenarios.

Comment: I think it also works if the domain is a differentiable manifold.